# Merging and sum up several value-counts series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

I usually use `value_counts()` to get the number of occurrences of a value. However, I deal now with large database-tables (cannot load it fully into RAM) and query the data in fractions of 1 month.

Is there a way to store the result of `value_counts()` and merge it with / add it to the next results?

I want to count the number user actions. Assume the following structure of 
user-activity logs:

```
# month 1
id    userId     actionType
1     1          a
2     1          c
3     2          a
4     3          a
5     3          b

# month 2
id    userId     actionType
6     1          b
7     1          b
8     2          a
9     3          c
```

Using `value_counts()` on those produces:

```
# month 1
userId
1       2
2       1
3       2

# month 2
userId
1       2
2       1
3       1
```

Expected output:

```
# month 1+2
userId
1       4
2       2
3       3
```

Up until now, I just have found a method using groupby and sum:

```
# count users actions and remember them in new column
df1['count'] = df1.groupby(['userId'], sort=False)['id'].transform('count')
# delete not necessary columns
df1 = df1[['userId', 'count']]
# delete not necessary rows
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['userId'])

# repeat
df2['count'] = df2.groupby(['userId'], sort=False)['id'].transform('count')
df2 = df2[['userId', 'count']]
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['userId'])

# merge and sum up
print pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(['userId'], sort=False).sum()
```

What is the pythonic / pandas' way of merging the information of several series' (and dataframes) efficiently?

Answer (score 5):

Let me suggest "add" and specify a fill value of 0. This has an advantage over the previously suggested answer in that it will work when the two Dataframes have non-identical sets of unique keys.

```
# Create frames
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'User_id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 'a': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'User_id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 'a': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]})
```

Now add the the two sets of values_counts(). The `fill_value` argument will handle any NaN values that would arise, in this example, the 'd' that appears in `df1`, but not `df2`.

```
a = df1.User_id.value_counts()
b = df2.User_id.value_counts()
a.add(b,fill_value=0)
```

Comment: This answer works with the dataframe with Nan values. JAB's answer doesn't, even with dropNa True.

Answer (score 3):

You can sum the `series` generated by the `value_counts` method directly:

```
#create frames
df= pd.DataFrame({'User_id': ['a','a','b','c','c'],'a':[1,1,2,3,3]})
df1= pd.DataFrame({'User_id': ['a','a','b','b','c','c','c'],'a':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4]})
```

sum the series:

```
df.User_id.value_counts() + df1.User_id.value_counts()
```

output:

```
a    4
b    3
c    5
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

This is know as "Split-Apply-Combine". It is done in 1 line and 3-4 clicks, using a lambda function as follows.

1️⃣ paste this into your code:

```
df['total_for_this_label'] = df.groupby('label', as_index=False)['label'].transform(lambda x: x.count())
```

2️⃣ replace 3x `label` with the name of the column whose values you are counting (case-sensitive)

3️⃣ print df.head() to check it's worked correctly